# Classical and quantum mechanical expectation values

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

By Ehrenfest’s theorem one finds that the quantum operators $\hat{q}$ and $\hat{p}$ satisfy 
$$\frac{d \langle\hat{q}\rangle}{dt} = \frac{\langle\hat{p}\rangle}{m}$$ and
$$\frac{d \langle\hat{p}\rangle}{dt} = \langle F(\hat{q})\rangle$$
Classically, by applying Liouvilles theorem the canonical coordinates $p$ and $q$ satisfy 
$$\frac{d \langle q \rangle}{dt} = \frac{\langle p \rangle}{m}$$ and
$$\frac{d \langle p \rangle}{dt} = \langle F(q)\rangle$$

It seems to me that the relations yield identical predictions for the values of $q$ and $p$ if the potential is the harmonic oscillator, does that seem correct? Is this always the case?

Comment: The expectation value is in general, not the same as the classical value, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only true for potentials up to order two in the variables!

Thus it is correct for the harmonic oscillator.

better explained [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest-Theorem), unfortunately only in german ;-)

Comment: How would it fail for say the potential $V(x)=x^3$?

Comment: if you have a quadratic potential the force $F$ is a linear function of position. by linearity $ F(\langle x \rangle) = \langle F(x) \rangle$ which yields the classical analogon of EOM with $ x \mapsto \langle x \rangle$.